# javascript window.open not working when targeting _blank

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in the body of my page. It is supposed to open the login page in a new window then close the current window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('/login', '_blank');
    window.close();
</script>
```

It works if I change `_blank` to `_self` but this is not what I want!

Any ideas?

Comment: window.open function by default works as a new window/tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem**

I am afraid that your **browser** does not allow such script to **prevent popups**.

---

**The solution**

You browser (and his popup blockers) will typically only allow window.open if used during the processing of a user event (like a click). So you should try to redesign your script behaviour.

---

**Maybe another interesting approach**

Maybe you should consider using a nice popup-like jquery plugin like [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). This won't be blocked by your browser, since it's not a *real* popup.

---

You can write `window.open('/login')` instead of `window.open('/login', '_blank')`.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open()` will open new window only ,no  need to of `_blank` or`_self`

```
window.open('/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

So about name argument:

```
Optional. Specifies the target attribute or the name of the window. The following values are supported:
_blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
_parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
_self - URL replaces the current page
_top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
name - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the title of the new window)
```

So you don't need _blank because of default